# Looking for a story about Dante's Inferno

Tags: story-identification

The protagonist is an alcoholic novelist who falls from a balcony and dies in the first few pages. He finds himself in [Dante's Inferno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_%28Dante%29) where he goes through the levels of hell accompanied by a stoic figure. That's all I can remember. Any of this ring a bell?

Answer (score 16):

This may be [*Inferno*](http://smile.amazon.com/dp/B001F784EG/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=SGDFW3AUZIMZ&coliid=IDVEP716ZY61C) by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle.

Description (slightly modified from Amazon's to avoid spoilers):

> After being thrown out the window of his luxury apartment, science fiction writer Allen Carpentier wakes to find himself at the gates of hell. Feeling he's landed in a great opportunity for a book, he attempts to follow Dante's road map. Determined to meet Satan himself, Carpentier treks through the Nine Layers of Hell led by a guide, and encounters countless mental and physical tortures. As he struggles to escape, he's taken through new, puzzling, and outlandish versions of sin--recast for the present day.

The guide is later revealed to be

> Benito Mussolini

Comment: Don't read the sequel.